# Why can't my jenkins server run NPM Install?

Tags: node.js, azure, jenkins

I've set up Jenkins on Azure using Jenkins Cluster by Bitnami and I'm trying to set up a NodeJS Build.

Straight out the box I have just configured my user, installed and configured the NodeJS Plugin, and set up my build.

On attempting an `NPM INSTALL` I encounter the error:

```
npm ERR! path /root/.npm/_logs
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall scandir
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir \'/root/.npm/_logs\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'scandir',
npm ERR!   path: '/root/.npm/_logs' }
```

Out the box I'm also unable to use `sudo`. Obviously I want to be able to add and remove build slaves at will so I don't want to be doing anything too complex.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you resolve the issue ?

Comment: I've the same issue on AWS, did you solve it?

Comment: I ended up building the agents by hand and not using the main jenkins server at all - I'm still waiting for an answer to the above because I'd rather not do it that way. Had a few people tell me they've had the same issue so and I don't think I've done anything wrong so I must have hit some sort of bug somewhere.